# How to create navbar multi-level dropdowns

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs3, bootstrap-5

Right now I'm having trouble creating a navbar. I want it to be Multi-Level Dropdowns, but when I click More Services, it closes the main dropdowns. I've tried many methods but none of them work. I'm using Vue.js with Bootstrap.

```
   <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-body-tertiary">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-brand mb-0 h1">กำหนดมาตรฐานบุคลากรทั่วไป</div>
      </div>

      <button
        class="navbar-toggler"
        type="button"
        data-bs-toggle="collapse"
        data-bs-target="#navbarNav"
        aria-controls="navbarNav"
        aria-expanded="false"
        aria-label="Toggle navigation"
      >
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <router-link to="/home" class="nav-link">Home</router-link>
          </li>

          <!-- Dropdown ระดับ 1 -->
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a
              class="nav-link dropdown-toggle"
              href="#"
              id="navbarDropdown"
              role="button"
              data-bs-toggle="dropdown"
              aria-haspopup="true"
              aria-expanded="false"
            >
              Services
            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
              <router-link to="/service1" class="dropdown-item"
                >Service 1</router-link
              >
              <router-link to="/service2" class="dropdown-item"
                >Service 2</router-link
              >

              <!-- Dropdown ระดับ 2 -->
              <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a
                  class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle"
                  href="#"
                  id="nestedDropdown"
                  role="button"
                  data-bs-toggle="dropdown"
                  aria-haspopup="true"
                  aria-expanded="false"
                >
                  More Services
                </a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="nestedDropdown">
                  <router-link to="/service3" class="dropdown-item"
                    >Service 3</router-link
                  >
                  <router-link to="/service4" class="dropdown-item"
                    >Service 4</router-link
                  >
                </div>
              </li>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.navbar-nav .nav-link{
  color: #fff;
}
.dropend .dropdown-toggle{
  color: salmon;
  margin-left: 1em;
}
.dropdown-item:hover{
  background-color: lightsalmon;
  color: #fff;
}
.dropdown .dropdown-menu{
  display: none;
}
.dropdown:hover > .dropdown-menu, .dropend:hover > .dropdown-menu{
  display: block;
  margin-top: .125em;
  margin-left: .125em;
}
@media screen and (min-width:769px) {
  .dropend:hover > .dropdown-menu{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 100%;
  }
  .dropend .dropdown-toggle{
    margin-left: .5em;
  }
}
```

```html
  <html>
  <head>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  
  <body>
    <main>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark" style="background-color: salmon;">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <a class="navbar-brand fw-bold" href="#">Navbar DropDown</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
              Dropdown
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
              <li>
                <hr class="dropdown-divider">
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item dropend">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                  Dropdown
                </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
                  <li>
                    <hr class="dropdown-divider">
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item dropend">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                      Dropdown
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
                      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
                      <li>
                        <hr class="dropdown-divider">
                      </li>
                      <li class="nav-item dropend">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                          Dropdown
                        </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
                          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
                          <li>
                            <hr class="dropdown-divider">
                          </li>
                          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                        </ul>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link">Link</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <form class="d-flex" role="search">
          <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-light" type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
</nav>
</main>
</body>
</html>
```